# Typer Error in Kivy while running a simple pong tutorial

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm currently learning to use kivy with python. I'm following this tutorial of creating a simple pong game

https://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html

And when I reach the part where I'm attempting to animate the ball. I wrote the code exactly as the tutorial. I use F5 to run the program from IDLE and I get a

```
return game()
Type Error: 'PongGame' object is not callable
```

message in the interactive shell and the window of the game itself freezes. Any thoughts on how to fix this ? Thanks in advance

Here is the code I wrote (exactly as the tutorial):-

code for main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty,\
ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from random import randint


class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
       self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos


class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self):
      self.ball.center = self.center
      self.ball.velocity = Vector(4, 0).rotate(randint(0, 360))

   def update(self, dt):
      self.ball.move()

      # bounce off top and bottom
      if (self.ball.y < 0) or (self.ball.top > self.height):
          self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

      # bounce off left and right
      if (self.ball.x < 0) or (self.ball.right > self.width):
          self.ball.velocity_x *= -1


class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
       game = PongGame()
       game.serve_ball()
       Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
       return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

code for pong.kv

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50 
canvas:
    Ellipse:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size          

<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball

    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x-5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    Label:
        font_size: 70  
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"

   Label:
       font_size: 70  
       center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
       top: root.top - 50
       text: "0"

   PongBall:
      id: pong_ball
      center: self.parent.center
```

Comment: strange. `return game()` in the error message, but in your code `return game` (the latter is correct, the first tries to call the object!)

Answer (score 0):

In your files (Python and kv) you have several identation errors. Compare your code with the original one and you will find the errors.

For more information regarding identation look here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation.